# WDSL file contains operation but zeep "gives service has no operation error"

Tags: python, python-2.7, soap, wsdl, zeep

I am trying to call the operation in a wsdl. I cannot share the complete file but here is a sample of the file -

```
<wsdl:operation name="XXX_XXX_CANCEL"><wsp:Policy><wsp:PolicyReference URI="#OP_XXX_XXX_CANCEL"/></wsp:Policy><wsdl:input message="p1:XXX_Order"/><wsdl:output message="p1:Order_RESP"/></wsdl:operation></wsdl:portType><wsdl:binding name="XXX_XXX_CANCELBinding" type="p1:XXX_XXX_CANCEL"><soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"/><wsdl:operation name="XXX_XXX_CANCEL"><soap:operation soapAction="http://sap.com/xi/WebService/soap1.1" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"/><wsdl:input><soap:body use="literal" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"/></wsdl:input><wsdl:output><soap:body use="literal" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"/></wsdl:output></wsdl:operation></wsdl:binding><wsdl:service name="XXX_XXX_CANCELService"><wsdl:port name="XXX_XXX_CANCELPort" binding="p1:XXX_XXX_CANCELBinding"><soap:address location="x" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"/></wsdl:port></wsdl:service></wsdl:definitions>""
```

If i do `python -mzeep xxx.wsdl` on that file I see a service and port but not any operation and while trying to call the service I get `service has no operation XXX_XXX_Cancel`.

I am unable to figure out why this is happening.

Answer (score 2):

It could be the case that an error occured while trying to parse the operation types/elements. In that case zeep you show a warning. Do you have the complete output of python -mzeep? (see first few lines)

Comment: Got a similar problem as OP and I do get warnings when I run mzeep. Namely:

UserWarning: The wsdl:message for 'XXXX' contains invalid xsd types or elements
  warnings.warn(str(exc))


And a more general UserWarning that operation X was not found in port type Y.

I don't think I can share the WSDL though so this is probably a lost cause.

Comment: @tani-rokk did you find solution for this. im also facing the same issue

Comment: I don't think so. I haven't tried Zeep since around that time unfortunately.

Comment: @Thameem Any ideas how to fix this by now?

Comment: @aggsol it was 4 years back.. sorry i dont remember what i did...

Answer (score 1):

There exists a problem with the zeep package. If the operations use nested elements and normal elements. It will list only those services which are nested. One can check this with using pdb.set_trace and invoke dir(client.service).

It will list only those services which has nested elements in its wsdl.